# After deleting all bluetooth from the device manager, how to add it back?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, device-manager, hardware-detection, microsoft-surface-3

In futzing with `bluetooth` I seem to have removed bluetooth from the device manager itself.  How do initiate a scan to detect the internal hardware to then download the correct driver?

I've [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1663565/4531180):

```
`**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20210430235117
Username: DESKTOP-9AKB65V\Nicholas
RunAs User: DESKTOP-9AKB65V\Nicholas
Configuration Name: 
Machine: DESKTOP-9AKB65V (Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18363.0)
Host Application: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Process ID: 7256
PSVersion: 5.1.18362.1171
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.1171
BuildVersion: 10.0.18362.1171
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is devmgr.txt
PS C:\Users\Nicholas> ms-settings:bluetooth
ms-settings:bluetooth : The term 'ms-settings:bluetooth' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ms-settings:bluetooth
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ms-settings:bluetooth:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
ms-settings:bluetooth : The term 'ms-settings:bluetooth' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ms-settings:bluetooth
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ms-settings:bluetooth:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\Nicholas> start ms-settings:bluetooth
PS C:\Users\Nicholas> devmgr
devmgr : The term 'devmgr' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ devmgr
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (devmgr:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
devmgr : The term 'devmgr' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ devmgr
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (devmgr:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\Nicholas> start devmgr
>> TerminatingError(Start-Process): "This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified."
start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ start devmgr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ start devmgr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

PS C:\Users\Nicholas> start ms-devmgr
>> TerminatingError(Start-Process): "This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified."
start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ start ms-devmgr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
start : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ start ms-devmgr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

PS C:\Users\Nicholas>  devmgmt
PS C:\Users\Nicholas> diskpart
PS C:\Users\Nicholas> Get-PSDrive

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                                                    CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                                                    ---------------
Alias                                  Alias
C                 102.04         13.61 FileSystem    C:\                                                                                                                      Users\Nicholas
Cert                                   Certificate   \
Env                                    Environment
Function                               Function
HKCU                                   Registry      HKEY_CURRENT_USER
HKLM                                   Registry      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Variable                               Variable
WSMan                                  WSMan


PS C:\Users\Nicholas> Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                                                    CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                                                    ---------------
C                 102.05         13.60 FileSystem    C:\                                                                                                                      Users\Nicholas


PS C:\Users\Nicholas> Get-Volume

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining      Size
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------      ----
C           Windows      NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      13.6 GB 115.65 GB
                         NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     84.25 MB    517 MB


PS C:\Users\Nicholas> net use
New connections will be remembered.

There are no entries in the list.
PS C:\Users\Nicholas> exit
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20210430235838
**********************
`
```

but cannot see:

1.)  how to use the device manager from powershell
2.)  how to re-detect hardware to then load the deleted driver

Answer (score 1):

1. On powershell prompt, type `devmgmt` to open Device Manager. When it is opened, scan your PC for hardware changes.
2. OR you can run powershell as administrator, type `pnputil.exe /scan-devices` to scan the system for hardware changes.

pnputil is [available on version 2004 and later](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-command-syntax#:%7E:text=async-,available%20starting%20in%20windows%2010%20version%202004,-Scan).

Comment: I think this is the answer.  Not quite sure.